# PHP variable scope with nested include returned by function

Tags: php

Thanks in advance for any help. :)
Ok, here's my problem.
Simplified version of the code:
global space with include file

> include file where $var is defined and function is called that returns an include statement
>   include file returned by function and where $var is no longer accessible

Why is $var no longer accessible?

I suspect it has to do with the function or maybe I am missing something else.
The function is like so:

```
function blah() {
return include_once 'filename.php';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works as designed. Think of the code as if the includes weren't there: You're inside a function, which has its own scope. Global variables are not accessible there.

Your options:

- Pass the variable as a reference to `blah(&$variable)`
- Import the variable from global space using `global $varname`
- If you're on PHP 5.3, use the new [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) feature
- Use a fancy OOP construct like Static classes, Singletons or Dependency Injection (probably overkill)

Comment: Or return an array that contains all the values you want to "export".

Comment: thanks guys, I changed the function to just return the file instead of the whole include statement, easy solution - just how I like it :)

Comment: For completeness, some other excellent suggestions (and code samples) are given in answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525310/alias-to-include