# alias to include

Tags: php

i have alias to `include()` in my `functions.php` file:

```
function render_template($template)
{
    include($template);
}
```

and simple `template.html` :

```
Hello, <?php echo $name ?>
```

But unfortunately, alias function gave me this output:

```
require 'functions.php';

$name = "world";

include('template.html');           // Hello, world
render_template('template.html');     // PHP Notice:Undefined variable: name
```

why is that? and how i can fix this?

thanks.

Comment: well, you cna ste it global or just a pramater to give it to `render_template`

Comment: Because of variable scope. Store all your template data into array and pass it to your render function

Comment: Try reading here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two more options to make it work around the scope issue. (Using global would require localising a long list of vars. Also it's not actually clear if your $name resides in the global scope anyway and always.)

First you could just turn your render_template() function into a name-resolver:

```
 function template($t) { 
    return $t;    // maybe add a directory later on
 }
```

Using it like this:

```
 $name = "world";
 include(template('template.html'));
```

Which is nicer to read and has obvious syntactical meaning.

---

The more quirky alternative is capturing the local variables for render_template:

```
 $name = "world";
 render_template('template.html', get_defined_vars());
```

Where render_template would require this addition:

```
function render_template($template, $vars)
{
    extract($vars);    // in lieu of global $var1,$var2,$var3,...
    include($template);
}
```

So that's more cumbersome than using a name-resolver.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `$name` is not visible at the point where `include` is called (inside function `render_template`). One way to fix it would be:

```
function render_template($template)
{
    global $name;
    include($template);
}
```

Comment: This, while a valid solution syntacticlyy, is however considered a bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Its a Scope Problem, you can set the variable to global, or encapsulate the whole thing a little bit more, for example like that:

```
class view{
    private $_data;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_data = new stdClass();
    }

    public function __get($name){
        return $this->_data->{$name};
    }

    public function __set($name,$value){
        $this->_data->{$name} = $value;
    }

    public function render($template){
        $data = $this->_data;
        include($template);
    }
}

$view = new view;

$view->name = "world";

$view->render('template.html');
```

template.html :

```
Hello <?php print $data->name; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* `$name` is in the global scope then you can get around it by declaring the variable global with the function. But a better solution would be to re-architect the code to require passing the relevant variable value into the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected.

Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

You would be interested in the following quote, "*If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it had been defined inside that function. So, it will follow the variable scope of that function. An exception to this rule are magic constants which are evaluated by the parser before the include occurs*".